# R libraries and paths - overview

Tags: r, file

I am using R Studio with R version 3.1.
I am a bit confused about how the overall file paths and conventions work. 
If someone has a link to a good explanation that would be great.

I want to know if a package needs to be installed into the working directory ie do i need to set  lib = "/xx/yy/zz" to the same place as the getwd() returns ?

I have supposedly succesfully installed RWeka   ---   package ‘RWeka’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
however when I try  "library("RWeka")   i get the

```
"Error in library("Rweka") : there is no package called ‘Rweka’   "
```

After I had installed the package it said

```
"package ‘RWeka’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
The downloaded binary packages are in
    Installing package into ‘C:/Users/MY NAME/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

hence the question -  are all packages downloaded to the place where R is installed and thats ok as long as all the code and files we are trying to access are in the set working director.

Many thanks

Here is the train 
RWeka installed successfully
however library(RWeka) shows the following

install.packages("RWeka")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/My Name/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/RWeka_0.4-23.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 535623 bytes (523 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 523 Kb

package ‘RWeka’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOc8SpX\downloaded_packages

> library(RWeka)
>   Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RWeka’

So I guess the questions are
1. Something else to do other than installing Java from Java.com  (have uninstalled and reinstalled no change)
2. I am using R 3.1.1

Comment: The packages are usually downloaded to one of the folders in `.libPaths()`  You can use `sapply(.libPaths(), list.files)` to see what's in each (if there is more than one folder)

Comment: The directory for packages could differ from that for working directory. Some people like to create a "Rfiles" folder at root directory to separate working files from R program and packages.

Comment: Package names are case sensitive. Try `library(RWeka)`

Comment: R is slowly going down in my opinion, its getting messy with `dplyr`s naming convention and process of intallation of new libraries is not as smooth as previously, which gave `R`s huge against against `python` for example

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are running R or R Studio on 32 or 64 bit version. Java and R must both be running the same version of architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Andy / Prakash are correct - the  function in R

Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")   will tell you whether you are running the 32 bit or 64 bit version of R

64 bit java can be downloaded here.

https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml#Java%20for%2064-bit